# Is there an axiomatic foundation for n-dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

In *The Elements*, Euclid establishes a set of axioms that dictate the behaviour of the plane.  Hilbert refined these axioms to actually prove every proposition of *The Elements* formally.  In Hartshorne's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*, the author shows that any Hilbert Plane satisfying $P$ (the Parallel Postulate) and $D$ (Dedekind's Axiom) is isomorphic to the real cartesian plane.  This basically allows us to use analytical methods of geometry in the plane and know that we are fully encapsulating every truth about the plane.

How do we extend this to $n$-dimensional Euclidean space? Are there axioms of space that we want to satisfy which justify our use of ordered tuples of real numbers?  Intuitively it seems right.  But I'm looking for a rigorous justification.  In Hartshorne, he omits an axiomatization of three dimensional Euclidean space.  Does one exist?

Comment: The cheapest way is to simply start with axioms of a real vector space. Euclid would not have approved of this, of course. I had seen synthetic axioms of $E^3$, but not for higher-dimensional spaces. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069518/problem-of-axiomatic-euclidean-geometry/1074860#1074860).

Answer (score 1):

Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry* provides an axiomatization for 3 dimension euclidean space based on points, lines and planes.

Tarski's geometry is based on a single sort (Points) and is modular wrt. dimension: on can choose the lower and upper dimension axioms.
On can find the statements for the lower and upper dimension axioms page 182 of *Tarski's system of geometry* by Tarski and Givant (http://www.geographicknowledge.de/SeminarLFG/TarskisSystemofElementaryGeometry.pdf).
For a systematic and very rigorous development of geometry based on these axioms see the book  *Metamathematische Methoden in der Geometrie*.